# Format in which the files that are sent as input to curl --data and --data-encode need to written

Tags: linux, http, post, curl, http-post

This works:

```
curl -k -d 'VARTEST=vartest2&TEXTPARAM=text1%0Atext2&COMMENT=abc22' http://localhost:8080/job/TEST1/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec

curl -X POST -k 'http://localhost:8080/job/TEST1/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&VARTEST=vartest2&TEXTPARAM=text1%0Atext2&COMMENT=abc22'
```

I want to be able to write the parameters to `-d` into a file and run the command line like this

```
curl -k -d @persargfile 'http://localhost:8080/job/TEST1/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec' -o abc.html
```

OR like this

```
curl -k --data-urlencode @persargfile 'http://localhost:8080/job/TEST1/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec' -o abc.html
```

Question:

What should be the format of the persargfile?

Answer (score 0):

As the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) states, there are several formats available:

- ascii        (--data-ascii)
- urlencoded   (--data-urlencoded)
- binary       (--data-binary)

It looks like for your application the `ascii` option is required. Meaning your file should contain:

```
VARTEST=vartest2&TEXTPARAM=text1%0Atext2&COMMENT=abc22
```

Comment: Can you show me how would I write the file for `--data-urlencoded` format?

Comment: `--data-urlencoded` is the only way how you could transfer the variables. `--data-binary` is for file uploads. I'm unsure for what `--data-ascii` is for, but for vars `urlencoded` is the way to go

Comment: What you explained is for `--data-ascii` option not for `--data-urlencoded` option.

Comment: Yes have tried it you are right. Have updated the answer. Still unsure how this `urlencode` should work with files